# Apache POI: Changes applied to the wrong slide

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a very weird behavior when upgrading from *Apache POI 3.17* to *5.x*.

With the new *Apache POI* version, the text replacement is done on the wrong slides. It modifies the original template slide instead of doing the modification on the copied one.

I use an existing presentation which has a “template” slide. This template slide is copied, and then certain text is replaced. This worked perfectly with the old version.

Here the code I use for creating the copy of the template slide:

```
SlideShow slides = new XMLSlideShow(inputStream);
XSLFSlide template = slides.getSlides().get(SLIDE_INDEX_TEMPLATE);

XSLFSlide newSlide = slides.createSlide(template.getSlideLayout());
newSlide.importContent(template);
```

And here is the simplified version of the text replacement:

```
for (XSLFShape shape: slide) {
    if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
        XSLFTextShape textShape = (XSLFTextShape) shape;
        List<XSLFTextParagraph> textBoxParagraphs = textShape.getTextParagraphs();
        List<XSLFTextRun> textBoxParagraphTextRuns = textBoxParagraphs.stream().map(XSLFTextParagraph::getTextRuns).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (XSLFTextRun r : textBoxParagraphTextRuns) {
            r.setText("Replaced!");
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I did wrong or any changes in *Apache POI* which could have broken this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `apache poi 4` the apache developers decided using `org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.*` for text paragraphs and text runs also in `XSLF`. Up to `apache poi 3.17` `XSLF` had have it's own classes for text paragraphs and text runs. Those are further present (maybe for backwards compatibility) but in versions greater than `apache po 3.17` they are using the wrong text body when text shapes are copied from other slides. I have not found where exactly this happens but the following shows that it is true.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class PPTXCCopyTemplateSlideAndChange {
    
 static final int SLIDE_INDEX_TEMPLATE = 0;
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XMLSlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("./PPTXIn.pptx"));

  XSLFSlide template = slideShow.getSlides().get(SLIDE_INDEX_TEMPLATE);

  XSLFSlide newSlide = slideShow.createSlide(template.getSlideLayout());
  newSlide = newSlide.importContent(template);

  for (XSLFShape shape: newSlide) {

   if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
    XSLFTextShape textShape = (XSLFTextShape) shape;
    
    //textShape.setText("Replaced!"); // this would work using apache poi 3.17 as well as using apache poi 5.2.2
    
/*  this works using apache poi 3.17 only but uses the wrong text body in version 5  
    List<XSLFTextParagraph> textBoxParagraphs = textShape.getTextParagraphs();
    List<XSLFTextRun> textBoxParagraphTextRuns = textBoxParagraphs.stream().map(XSLFTextParagraph::getTextRuns).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (XSLFTextRun r : textBoxParagraphTextRuns) {
     r.setText("Replaced!");
    }
*/

///*  this works using apache poi 5.2.2 only but cannot work using version 3.17 because of usage of org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.*
    List<org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.XDDFTextParagraph> textBoxParagraphs = textShape.getTextBody().getParagraphs();
    List<org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.XDDFTextRun> textBoxParagraphTextRuns = textBoxParagraphs.stream().map(org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.XDDFTextParagraph::getTextRuns).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.XDDFTextRun r : textBoxParagraphTextRuns) {
     r.setText("Replaced!");
    }
//*/

   }
  }
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./PPTXOut.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```

Here `textShape.setText("Replaced!");` works using `apache poi 3.17` as well as using `apache poi 5.2.2` as `XSLFTextShape.setText` uses the underlying `CTTextBody` directly even in version 5. But of course using that you have no control over the different text runs.

`List<XSLFTextParagraph> textBoxParagraphs = textShape.getTextParagraphs();` works using `apache poi 3.17` only but uses the wrong text body in version 5. Maybe because `XSLFAutoShape.getTextBody(boolean create)` also uses `org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.XDDFTextBody` instead of only using the underlying `CTTextBody` directly. But not really sure.

`List<org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.XDDFTextParagraph> textBoxParagraphs = textShape.getTextBody().getParagraphs();` works using `apache poi 5.2.2` only but cannot work using version 3.17 because of usage of `org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.*` which is not known in version 3.17.

So, as often, you have to code totally different for different versions of `apache poi`. There is no backwards compatibility, even it was probably tried here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this prompt answer. Switching to XDDF worked. Maybe the devs could mention that somewhere, since XDDF seems to be marked as beta.