# Problem with Apache POI in Mendix: Changes to Cloned Slide Reflected on Original

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, clone

I'm working on a Mendix project and am facing a peculiar issue with Apache POI. I've got a function that's meant to modify a cloned PowerPoint slide, but instead, it seems to modify the original slide. I'm surprised because other functions that add tables and change images work perfectly, reflecting changes in the expected places. It's almost as if Apache POI is ignoring the slide I'm passing and operating on the original.

Here's the code:

```
public IMendixObject executeAction() throws Exception {
    // Fetching presentation Slides from the Slides_ConfigurationBios relationship
    IMendixObject slidesObj = Core.retrieveByPath(getContext(), this.ConfigurationBios.getMendixObject(), "Exporter.Slides_ConfigurationBios").get(0);
    InputStream originalContentStream = Core.getFileDocumentContent(getContext(), slidesObj);
    XMLSlideShow mainPpt = new XMLSlideShow(originalContentStream);
    XSLFSlide templateSlide = mainPpt.getSlides().get(0);

    // Retrieving list of PersonsToExport associated with ConfigurationBios
    List<IMendixObject> personsToExportList = Core.retrieveByPath(getContext(), this.ConfigurationBios.getMendixObject(), "Exporter.PersonsToExport_ConfigurationBios");

    // Iterating through the list of PersonsToExport
    for (IMendixObject personToExport : personsToExportList) {
        // Retrieving list of Person associated with PersonsToExport
        List<IMendixObject> personList = Core.retrieveByPath(getContext(), personToExport, "Exporter.PersonsToExport_Person");
        for (IMendixObject person : personList) {
            // Fetching the PersonImage object associated with the Person object
            IMendixObject personImageObj = Core.retrieveByPath(getContext(), person, "Persons.PersonImage_Person").get(0);
            persons.proxies.PersonImage PersonImage = personImageObj == null ? null : persons.proxies.PersonImage.initialize(getContext(), personImageObj);

            // Cloning the template slide
            XSLFSlide clonedSlide = mainPpt.createSlide().importContent(templateSlide);

            // Calling functions to modify the cloned slide
            Map<String, String> replacements = generateReplacementsMap(clonedSlide, person);
            replaceTextInSlide(clonedSlide, replacements);

            if (PersonImage != null && PersonImage.getMendixObject() != null) {
                replaceImageInSlide(clonedSlide, PersonImage);
            }

            // [Other functions which seem to work fine]
        }
    }

    // Removing the original template slide
    mainPpt.removeSlide(0);

    // Saving the modified presentation to the Slides object
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    mainPpt.write(byteOutput);
    Core.storeFileDocumentContent(getContext(), slidesObj, new ByteArrayInputStream(byteOutput.toByteArray()));

    return slidesObj;
}

private Map<String, String> generateReplacementsMap(XSLFSlide slide, IMendixObject person) {
    Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
    // Search for text on the slide contained between "[#" and "#]"
    for (XSLFShape shape : slide.getShapes()) {
        if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
            XSLFTextShape textShape = (XSLFTextShape) shape;
            for (XSLFTextParagraph paragraph : textShape.getTextParagraphs()) {
                for (XSLFTextRun run : paragraph.getTextRuns()) {
                    String text = run.getRawText();
                    if (text.contains("[#") && text.contains("#]")) {
                        String attributeName = text.substring(text.indexOf("[#") + 2, text.indexOf("#]"));
                        IMendixObjectMember<?> member = person.getMember(getContext(), attributeName);
                        if (member != null) {
                            String replacementValue = member.getValue(getContext()) != null ? member.getValue(getContext()).toString() : "[!FIELD MISSING!]";
                            replacements.put("[#" + attributeName + "#]", replacementValue);
                        } else {
                            replacements.put("[#" + attributeName + "#]", "[!FIELD MISSING!]");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return replacements;
}

private void replaceTextInSlide(XSLFSlide slide, Map<String, String> replacements) {
    for (XSLFShape shape : slide.getShapes()) {
        if (shape instanceof XSLFTextShape) {
            XSLFTextShape textShape = (XSLFTextShape) shape;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : replacements.entrySet()) {
                String find = entry.getKey();
                String replace = entry.getValue();
                textShape.getTextParagraphs().forEach(paragraph -> {
                    paragraph.getTextRuns().forEach(run -> {
                        String text = run.getRawText();
                        if (text.contains(find)) {
                            run.setText(text.replace(find, replace));
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After the presentation is created, and before I remove the first slide (which is the original), I can see that changes regarding text replacements have been made to it. Other changes, however, are appropriately made to the cloned slides.

Any insights or suggestions on why this might be happening or how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved my problem! It seems that Apache POI has made some changes in version 4 that affect the way you work with text in PPTX slides. The problem I'm facing is due to these changes. Specifically, it relates to the use of XSLFTextParagraph and XSLFTextRun, which in newer versions of POI use an incorrect text body (CTTextBody) after copying shapes from other slides.

I adjusted my code this way:
Instead of using XSLFTextParagraph and XSLFTextRun, I used org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.XDDFTextParagraph and org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.text.XDDFTextRun, which are newer classes for working with text in Apache POI.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72017058/apache-poi-changes-applied-to-the-wrong-slide/72017774#72017774